# How to display an ionic-footer above the tabs?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, ionic-framework

**How do I affix a footer to an Ionic tab's detail page and prevent it from hiding behind the tabs?**

I'm building an Ionic tabbed app and having issues with the footer properly displaying on a tab's detail page. I want to make the footer height smaller but this only pushes the footer lower underneath the Tabs.

### App Structure

```
Tabs
|-Tab 1
|--Detail page    (Place footer on this page above the tabs)
|-Tab 2
|-Tab 3
```

### detail.page.html

```
<ion-content></ion-content>
<ion-footer>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>Completed</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

### tabs.page.html

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
    <ion-tab-button tab="tab1">
      <ion-icon name="triangle-outline"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Mountains</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="tab2">
      <ion-icon name="star-outline"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Favorites</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="tab3">
      <ion-icon name="trophy-outline"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Progress</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
  </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
```

### Output

**Here is what I'm getting when I try styling the `<ion-toolbar style="height: 3vh">` to have a height property:**

[image]

### **Desired output**

(except I want the footer bar to be smaller height):

[image]

Comment: You could make a div with position absolute & margin-bottom 56px;